# AvAudioRecorder record to AsyncSocket NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder, asyncsocket

Hey everyone I am having quite a time trying to figure out what (should be) pretty straight forward. I have an open socket and I just want to pipe AAC audio data captured from the mic to it. It seems using AV recorder that you have to specify a file so I have a memory file specified. How to I capture and just pipe to the socket?

I was thinking maybe I need to set a timer and pull out the contents of the file on an interval but that seems like the wrong approach.

I am relatively new with iOS so any pointers would be helpful.

Once again the **ultimate goal** is to take this recorded data and push it to the socket in (pseudo) real-time.

Code to record the audio currently working just fine.

```
NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString *soundFilePath = [tempDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.m4a"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
//NSString *path = [soundFileURL absoluteString];
//NSLog(path);

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                nil];
NSError *error = nil;
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:soundFileURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];
if (!recorder) {
    NSLog(@"audioRecorder: %@ %d %@", [error domain], [error code], [[error userInfo] description]);
    return;
}

[recorder prepareToRecord];
session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];
[recorder record];
```

Code to send a standard string to socket with AsyncSocket:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lame thing passed%@"
                    "\r\n", standard_string];

string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:string];

NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[string release];

NSLog(@"Sending HTTP Request.");
[socket writeData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:5];
```

Comment: Also looking for a similar solution; hopefully someone responds (although this is 3 years so likely no one will). Did you solve your problem?